# Linear Algebra - Field of 2 elements

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on the following problem:

> $F = \mathbb{F}^2$ is the field of two elements. Let $U \subset F^4$ be the subspace generated by $(1,1,1,1),(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,0)$ and $V \subset F^4$ be generated by $(1,1,1,0), (0,1,1,1)$. Find the generations for $U \cap V$.

So here is what I got:

---

To determine generators for the intersection $ U \cap V$, we use the identity $U \cap V = (U^{\perp} + V^{\perp})^{\perp}$. The subspaces of $U^{\perp}$ and $V^{\perp}$ equal the kernel of the matrices

$M = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $N = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ respectively, where the rows of $M$ are $u_1, u_2,u_3$ and those of $N$ are $v_1, v_2$.
The reduced row echelon form of $M$ and $N$ are $M' = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $N' = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. The dimensions of $U$ and $V$ equal the number of nonzero rows in $M$ and $N$ respectively, so $\dim(U) = 3$ and $\dim(V) = 2$. The kernels $\ker M' = \ker M = U^{\perp}$ and $\ker N' = \ker N = V^{\perp}$ are generated by ${a_1}$ and ${b_1, b_2}$ respectively, with $$a_1 =   \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    1 \\
    -1 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix}, b_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    -1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}, b_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix} $$

Therefore the subspace $U^{\perp} + V^{\perp}$ is generated by $a_1, b_1, b_2$, so the subspace $U \cap V = (U^{\perp} + V^{\perp})^{\perp}$ is the kernel of the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
    0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

The reduced row echelon form of this matrix is $$ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix} $$

So the kernel $U \cap V $ is generated by the vector $(1,2,2,1)$.

---

However, I'm wondering if this is correct because nowhere did I use the fact that $F$ is "the field of two elements", and I don't really know what its significance is anyway. So, is my solution correct, and if so, where does the "field of two elements" thingamajig come to play?

Comment: The field of two elements has the effect that $F^4$ only has $16$ elements, and as such, you could check this by brute force if you wanted to. $U$ has $8$ elements and $V$ has four.

Comment: In a field of two elements what is $2$??

Comment: In the field $\mathbf F_2$, (and any field with characteristic $2$), $2=0$,$-1=1$ and substracting is the same as adding.